# Any idea of how to change the type of quotes in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, quotes

On my wordpress website, the articles have quotes that look like this :
« xxxx » stuff bla bla bla

How can I transform those « » quotes to look more like ' or ", therefore using less space in the meta og / google description?
But also in a way so that it doesnt break the codes for the title/descriptions etc?

Any ideas?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming all your <<< stuff is in the content. Try using this link as a reference.

https://www.thewebtaylor.com/articles/wordpress-replace-string-in-content-of-all-pages

```
function replace_content($content)
{
  $content = str_replace('<<', '"',$content);
  $content = str_replace('>>', '"',$content);
  $content = str_replace('&lt;&lt;', '"',$content);
  $content = str_replace('&gt;&gt;', '"',$content);
  return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content','replace_content');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i'll check this out.
But I tend to think that the original conversion is already in wordpress.
I'll check the functions.php